# Why do we not try to describe $4$d quantum gravity with a $3$d CFT?

Tags: gravity, string-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-gravity, ads-cft

In AdS/CFT correspondence, one mostly studies the case with AdS$_5 \times$ S$_5$ on the string side and $4$d $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super Yang-Mills on the gauge field theory side. Real-world observations show that gravity occurs in a $4$-dimensional Universe, possibly with compact dimensions. Then would it not be more interesting to look at correspondences between AdS$_4$ and $3$d CFT? In that way, one would hope to be able to describe $4$d quantum gravity with a $3$d Yang-Mills theory or something. Maybe the reason is that this implies giving up on the Standard Model, but when I think about it I do not see an obvious reason why this should be necessary at first (maybe in latter stages though).

Note that I am putting aside for now the fact that AdS space does not seem to reproduce our Universe. Also, I am aware that there actually exists such dualities in the literature, but they seem more academic-oriented, in the sense that their aim is not to describe reality (maybe I am wrong?). And of course I can imagine the $\mathcal{N}=4$ being useful for practical purposes if one tries to describe e.g. QCD with string theory.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ABJM?

Comment: @Konstantinos No, I just looked at the (very short) wikipedia article that says it is dual to a Ads$_4$ theory. What about it? Does it aim at describing realistic 4d quantum gravity?

Comment: I am not an expert on ABJM but I just mentioned it because it is related in general to the AdS$_4$/CFT$_3$ nature of the question you asked. And I am not really sure what you mean when you say realistic, so it is kind of difficult to answer so broadly.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Good point, let me try to make that clearer by reformulating the question: if I were to say "I am going to try to find a path to $4$d quantum gravity, first by studying AdS$_4$/CFT$_3$ duality, from which I hope to understand some general mechanisms of $4$d gravity, and then by trying to extend that duality beyond AdS spacetime", would there be any reason for you to answer "Stop, this is going nowhere. Gauge/gravity duality with a $4$d gravity side has no chance to succeed in describing the world in which we live."?

Answer (score 2):

It is crucial to understand that in the $AdS_{5} \times S^{5}$ realization of holography spacetime is percieved as ten dimensional by any bulk observer because the radius of $S^{5}$ is macroscopic (much larger that the string lenght). Then $AdS_{5} \times S^{5}$ is not defining 5-dimensional quantum gravity by means of a SCFT.

All the known consistent examples of holography are constructed as the [near horizon geometry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/near-horizon+geometry#:%7E:text=The%20spacetime%20geometry%20of%20a,near%20and%20far%20horizon%20geometry.) of some piles of branes in string theory. The resulting bulk geometries are always of the form $AdS_{d} \times (something)$, always with ten or eleven macroscopic dimensions and never of the form $AdS_{d}$ (such as the case of pure gravity in 3d) or $AdS_{d} \times K$ where $K$ is some compact geometry as needed to describe 4d quantum gravity.

In that sense, $AdS/CFT$ is not a useful phenomenological scenario as the usual string theory compactifications are. A parametric separation between the KK-scale and the Hubble scale is the most basic requirement for phenomenology that is abscent in holographic setups.

**Update:** I recently learned that the path integral of three dimensional Chern-Simons theory can be viewed (under some hypothesis) as equivalent to $\mathcal{N}$=4 SYM in four dimensions. Reference: [A new look at the path integral in quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6032).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, but I'm probably missing something. Could you highlight where the 4 dimensional gravity comes up?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti You're absolutely right, I'm not answering the question in any sense. My "answer" is just a long comment trying to point out the fact that we don't have any example of holography in which a bulk observer experiences 4d effective physics.  Therefore is not immediately possible to argue that the 4-dimensional physics we observe suggests a holographic realization of our universe in 3d terms; as the question explicitly says.